# How to send request through corporate firewall

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, windows-firewall

I want to send web service request through the firewall. I am having one restlet web service on my PC, and i want to access that web service from my laptop.

For that i did following things.

1. I have started my web server on my PC port 8080.
2. I have created proxy which redirect port 80 requests to 8080.
3. I have added two `Inbounded` rules in firewall.

   - added TCP proxy with port 80.
   - added UDP proxy with port 80.

Now, `localhost:8080` and `localhost:80` both working fine in my PC. But, I am not able to open using `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80` from my laptop.

If i am turn off my firewall and then try to access `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80` from my laptop and it's working good.

Can anyone tell me what i am missing to configure proxy in firewall?

Answer (score 0):

**I Found the solution**

I have referred [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) to cross check my configuration. I found that troubleshooting will automatically find and fix some common problems.

So, I just run windows troubleshooter to find out problem. And as mention in tutorial, troubleshooting has fixed my issue.